# Наибольшие паросочетания в двудольных графах

Tags: алгоритм, графы

какими алгоритмами можно решить данную задачу (*Наибольшие паросочетания в двудольных графах*) кроме как алгоритмами Куна и Хопкрофта — Карпа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подойдёт [любой метод для нахождения  максимального потока](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5) с добавлением фиктивных истока и стока.

Форд-Фалкерсон попроще Хопкрофта — Карпа, но последний эффективнее.

Comment: не знаете где можно найти реализации этих алгоритмов желательно на c++ подстроенные как раз под мою задачу?

Comment: [HK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hopcroft-karp-algorithm-for-maximum-matching-set-2-implementation/), [FF](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/?ref=rp), [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/)